# is there any way to achive growing div animation with transform properties?

Tags: css

I've developed an animation in which a div grows by using the following styles:

```
.animation-start {
   overflow: hidden;
   height: 0;
}

.animation-end {
   height: 100px;
}
```

But the problem with this approach is that it is not rendered smoothly on mobile devices. At the moment the only animations rendered smoothly on mobiles are the ones that use `transform` property. Is there any way to achive growing div animation with solely transform properties (without using height property)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A transition and transform property should be able to handle this for you

```
transition: all 0.5s ease;
transform: scale(2);

// Or individually target the axis you want to scale
transform: scaleX(2);
transform: scaleY(2);
```

Scale works as a multiplier but I'm not sure if you need a fixed pixel height

Comment: Better to use `scaleY()`.

Comment: thanks, can you please provide simple plunker\jsfiddle example? I don't undertand how can `scale` help here

Comment: @HashemQolami, any idea if it's possible at all what I'm trying to do?

Comment: @Maximus `transform` will change the element visually. i.e. it will overlap the other elements in the layout, is that okay?

Comment: @HashemQolami, yeah, that's OK, since I'm going to position absolutely anyway above all content since absolutely positioned elements cause less reflows

Comment: @Maximus Have a look at http://jsbin.com/dojupa/1/edit?css,js,output - Click on toggle button to see the effect.

Comment: @HashemQolami, yeah, that seems like a good solution, thanks a lot!  I still need to understand how `scale` does this effect though, will try to figure that out.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can just add a duration to the element:

```js
$(document).click(function(){
    $('div').toggleClass('animation-end');
});
```

```css
div {
    background: #ffc;
    transition-duration: 300ms;
}
.animation-start {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 0;
}
.animation-end {
    height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="animation-start">asdf</div>
click anywhere
```

Comment: thanks, but you're using `height`, I was asking whether `height` and can be replaced with some transition properties?